# DEFLATE: how to handle "no distance codes" case?

Tags: gzip, huffman-code, deflate

I mostly get RFC 1951, however I'm not too clear on how to manage the case where (when using dynamic Huffman tables) no distance codes are needed or present. For example, let's take the input:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890987654321ZYXWVUTSR
```

where no backreference is possible since there are no repetitions of length >= 3.
According to RFC 1951, at least one distance code must be present regardless, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to encode HDIST - 1. I understand, according to the reference, that such code should be of zero bits to signal "no distance codes".

> One distance code of zero bits means that there are no distance codes
> used at all (the data is all literals).

In infgen symbols, I'd expect to see a `dist 0 0`.

Analyzing what gzip does with infgen, however, I see that TWO distance codes are emitted (each 1 bit long) for the above input (even though none is actually used then):

```
! infgen 2.4 output
!
gzip
!
last
dynamic
litlen 48 6
litlen 49 6
litlen 50 6
...cut...
litlen 121 6
litlen 122 6
litlen 256 6
dist 0 1
dist 1 1
literal 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890987654321Z
literal 'YXWVUTSR
end
!
crc
length
```

So what's the correct behavior in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no matches in the deflate block, there will be no lengths from the length/literal code, and so the decoder will never look for a distance code. In that case, what would make the most sense is to provide no information at all about a distance code.

However the format does not permit that, since the 5-bit `HDIST` value in the header is interpreted as 1 to 32 distance codes, for which lengths must be provided for in the header. You must provide at least one distance code length in the header, even though it will never be used.

There are several valid things you can do in that case. RFC 1951 notes you can provide a single distance code (HDIST == 0, meaning one length), with length zero, which would be just one zero in the list of lengths.

It is also permitted to provide a single code of length one, or you could do as zlib is doing, which is to provide two codes of length one. You can actually put any valid distance code description you like there, and it will still be accepted.

As to why zlib's deflate is choosing to define two codes there, I can only guess that Jean-loup was being conservative, writing something he knew that even an over-simplified inflator would have to accept. Both gzip and zopfli do the same thing. They all do the same thing when there is only one distance code used. They could emit just the single one-bit distance code, per the RFC, but they emit two single-bit distance codes, one of which is never used.

Really the right thing to do would be to write a single zero length as noted in the RFC, which would take the fewest number of bits in the header. I will consider updating zlib to do that, to eke out a few more bits of compression.

Comment: NB: in Zopfli's deflate.c it is done in the `PatchDistanceCodesForBuggyDecoders` function...